# How to add to a new dataframe the preceding rows! R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, rows

I have a date frame which looks approximately in the next way:

```
x<-c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0)
y<-c(12,12,3,45,6,5,63,2,3,4,5)
z<-data.frame(x,y)
z
#   x  y
#1  0 12
#2  0 12
#3  0  3
#4  0 45
#5  0  6
#6  1  5
#7  1 63
#8  1  2
#9  0  3
#10 1  4
#11 0  5
```

I would like to run a function or loop which find the rows in `x` which equals to `1` and add to a new data frame this row and the 4 preceding rows.

Comment: `which(z$x==1)` gives you the indices for which x is 1. Do you want the four preceding rows for all these indices?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes exactly for each of them

Comment: Do you then want four dataframes (for the ones in row 6,7,8,10 of `z`)? Then you could do: `lapply(which(z$x==1), function(x)z[(x-4):x,])`. Or do you want to have just one data frame at the end?

Comment: What do you do e.g. in row 10: include this row and the four preceding ones again? This is a bit like @user1981275's comment

Comment: Thanks a lot , I can just add rbind.fill (from plyr package) to create one dataframe. Works perfectly.

Comment: It will fail if a 1 occurs in the first four rows, you need to add a small fix there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small riff to @user1981275 solution with a small fix if there are no preceding rows to avoid negative indexing

```
l <- lapply(which(z$x==1), function(x) {
  z[(ifelse(x-4 < 1, 1, x-4)):x,]
})
do.call(rbind, l)
```

Comment: sorry, I do not understand your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index:

```
z[sapply(which(as.logical(z$x)), function(x) seq(x - 4, x)), ]
```